# Unit Root Test for Panel Data in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, unit-root

I'm working with a **unbalanced** panel dataset of 18 countries with quarterly data from 1970 to 2014 of different characteristics per country (housing prices, education level, total population, GDP per Capita)

Now I want to figure out if these characteristics have unit roots in them.

My Question is If I should run a test per country per characteristic like this:
`adf.test(subset(HPI[which(HPI!="NA")],Country=="Germany"), k=4)`

or if I should run the test only once per characteristic:

`adf.test(HPI[which(HPI!="NA")], k=4)`

Answer (score 0):

Neither nor. Look for unit root tests specifially designed for panel, i.e. panel unit root test. Just search for that term for your favourite statistical package.